# Framework not found MicrosoftBandKit_iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, microsoft-band

Error:

```
Ld DerivedData/SenseWatch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SenseWatch.app/SenseWatch normal x86_64
cd /Users/Jieyi/Documents/Repo/SenseWatch
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -L/Users/Jieyi/Documents/Repo/SenseWatch/DerivedData/SenseWatch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Jieyi/Documents/Repo/SenseWatch/DerivedData/SenseWatch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Jieyi/Documents/Repo/SenseWatch/DerivedData/SenseWatch/Build/Intermediates/SenseWatch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SenseWatch.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SenseWatch.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework MicrosoftBandKit_iOS -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Jieyi/Documents/Repo/SenseWatch/DerivedData/SenseWatch/Build/Intermediates/SenseWatch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SenseWatch.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SenseWatch_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Jieyi/Documents/Repo/SenseWatch/DerivedData/SenseWatch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SenseWatch.app/SenseWatch

ld: framework not found MicrosoftBandKit_iOS
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I just created the project, added the framework in build phases. the framework is clearly under the project. but it still says not found. i know that it may needs to finish framework search path. but i don't understand how to? like put in the absolute path for the framework?

Comment: I notice you are targeting iOS 9. I am using Swift 2 and iOS 9.0.1 but for some reason I can not connect to the Band. It knows if there are no Bands available to connect but when I try to connect to a client it does nothing. Have you had success in connecting to the Band?

Comment: Did you install Microsoft Health App? And did you get client from attachedClients?

Comment: Yes, (MSBClient) client = 0x0000000147e4d500 {
  NSObject = {
    isa = 0x0000000147e4d500
  }
  _notificationManager = nil
  _personalizationManager = nil
  _tileManager = nil
  _sensorManager = nil
  _name = 0x0000000147e4df60 "Ste's Band 68:a2 LE"
  _connectionIdentifier = 0x0000000147e4d580
  _tileDelegate = nil
  _clientManager = 0x0000000147e485f0
  _deviceAgent = 0x0000000147e4dcc0
  _dispatchQueue = 0x0000000147e4d020
  _subscriptionSampleParser = nil
}

Comment: Apologies for the bad formatting but it's not directly related to the question so I don't want to add an answer.

Comment: well, in this case, I have no good answer. I did have it connected and do other stuff after with Swift 2 and iOS 9 GM. However, you may wanna try unpair in MS Health App, reset MS Band, and pair them again to try if its something else other than your code. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured it out. Although I was using import CoreBluetooth in my .swift file, it still required me to add it to the link with libraries section.

Comment: I remember I have this problem with missing CoreBluetooth long ago, however, in my on going project, everything works without the CoreBluetooth. That's why I didn't think of the solution. However, it is weird that it still works without CoreBluetooth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90556/discussion-between-ste-prescott-and-fullstackpug).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no absolute path is bad way, it only work in your computer, not work with your partner. Set relative path is best way. To set path for framework:

1. be sure framework locate in project folder
2. select target -> Build Setting -> Search Path-> Framework Search Paths. Double click it will show an Search Paths input text view
3. in Finder go to folder content framework. Drag this folder to search paths input text view. it will be some thing like "$(SRCROOT)/Vendors/FacebookSDK"
4. just remove double qoute "", result: $(SRCROOT)/Vendors/FacebookSDK

done!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if we have multiple files, It's hard to drag and drop that many files right...

Comment: dragging the folder and see that xcode create this SRCROOT string..teach me very good lesson. thanks. for other I say it's important to drag the folder without tapping + button.

Answer (score 0):

http://stationinthemetro.com/2014/06/04/copy-file-path-as-text-in-mac-os-x
i use this and copy the absolute path and put it under framework search path and it works