# Import a static library as a subproject

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com.br/watch?v=f7lxkv-sZA0) to know how to create a static library, I just watched until the 4:05 minute video (which have already been enough to learn how to create a static library).

But I learned that there's another way to import a static library for the project called subproject, for this I open my iphone project and add my library project (MuitosAlertas.xcodeproj), Then I added two references to my library inside the tab **Target Dependencies** and **Link Binary with libraries** as you can see below:

[image]

When I compile and run, Xcode give me the problem

> Lexical or preprocessor issue 'MuitosAlertas.h' file not found

I try to put inside **Other linker flags** the code **-ObjC** but without results, how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `Header Search Path` to your target. In build setting search "Header Search Path" and add relative link to your static library project. How to add relative path read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744761/framework-not-found-microsoftbandkit-ios/30745571#30745571)

You may need to search path with `recursive` option.

Comment: Thanks, I use this code and works great: $(SRCROOT)/../MuitosAlertas/MuitosAlertas

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created your Library then make a build from the target added separately for the Universal support and then by right clicking on to the .a file from bundle navigate to folder and look for Universal and copy Include folder and your StaticLibrary.a file, then where you want to use it paste in that project and add reference to it and in bundle setting you need to set the HeaderSearchPath of the library where it is kept and the OtherLinkerFlag to -ObjC.
Then import the headers of your library and use your methods.